# Compute the variance for x:

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, variance

```
Number of Times          Owner Occupied
0                              439   
1                              1100
2                              249
3                              98
4 or more                      120
Total                          2006
```

I'm really struggling with this one, any help would be greatly appreciated!
I also know that E(x)= 1.18, but don't know how to compute variance.

My professor wrote
$Var(x) = E(x²) – [E(x)]² = 6.7 – (1.18)² = 5.30$

But I do not know how to get 6.7
I know that it is the summation of all $x^2f(x)$, but I keep on getting 2.44

I did $0+0.55+0.48+0.45+0.96$

Comment: Please edit to show your efforts. What goes wrong when you apply the usual definitions?  Also, you should define the variable $X$.

Comment: I know that E(x)=1.18

Comment: Can you find the variance

Comment: I know that var(x)= E(x^2)-(E(x))^2 but I am not getting the correct answer

Comment: As an OP you are able to accept nice answers by clicking on the checkmark of an answer.

Comment: Could you find the variance?

Comment: You said you don't know how to compute variance. Fair enough; do you have a formula for variance? If not, try looking for one. If so, where have you encountered difficulty in applying it?

Comment: I stated the formula above, var(x)= E(x^2)-(E(x))^2

Comment: My professor got 5.30

Comment: But I got 1.26,

Comment: Got it -- I missed that comment. But still: you've said that you didn't get the right answer. Can you show your work (by editing your question, not in the comments) so that we can potentially find a mistake for you?

Comment: My professor said that E(x^2)=6.7, but I am struggling to understand

Comment: I edited it, and showed my work to best of my ability

Comment: @KrishAhluwalia I got $E(x^2)=2.44$ as well.

Comment: So am I correct, and my professor wrong? Is the variance 2.44-1.18=1.26?

Comment: Or sorry, var(x)=1.0476?

Comment: How do you deal with the "4 or more" entry? Do you just assign 4? (is $E(x)=1.18$ given or did you calculate it yourself?)

Comment: Yes, more or less. It depends how much decimal places you use. I have $Var(x)=1.0435$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what you've posted here, your professor's calculation of $\mathbb E[X^2] = 6.7$ does indeed appear to be incorrect.